# what is the implicit meaning of "It's generally easier to think"?

Tags: comparatives

I'm reading some material(git pro), then I encountered this context, I want to know what is the meaning of

> "It’s generally easier to think"

as far as I know, easier is comparative word, but In this phrase I can not find any comparable word (for example, a rabbit is faster than a turtle)
what is the same expression of this words?

original sentences :

> It’s generally easier to think about them as work silos, where sets
> of commits graduate to a more stable silo when they’re fully tested

Thank you

Comment: The implied comparison is "than other ways of thinking about them".

Comment: A comparative adjective can point backwards as well as forwards. "_A turtle covers 100 meters in 20 minutes. A rabbit is faster_". Presumably the sentence you quote follows an example of a way of thinking about (repositories?) which is less easy than thinking of them as work silos.

Comment: The thing that it's being compared to might also have been mentioned in a *previous* sentence that was not included in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comparison is to other real or imagined alternatives. If you are doing a job and advised "its generally easier to..." the comparison is to what you were doing. In this case the comparison is to what the author expects you might be using as a way of thinking of "them". "Easiest" might also be used in a similar situation, but the author may be concerned it sounds too prescriptive. Using "easier" is a weaker way of making the suggestion.